# JQuery Post to ASP.NET Core results in CORS error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post, cors

I have an ASP.NET Core API and a html-css-js client side. I try to send a post request to said API, but Firefox throws an error that the same origin policy forbids reading of external resource.

The `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                   {
                       options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                   });

    IGameManager gameManager = new GameManager();

    services.AddTransient<IGameManager>(gm => gameManager);
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors(options => 
                   options.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44314").AllowAnyMethod());
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                         { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

And the jQuery request:

```
var data = {
    Name : "Test"
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://localhost:44314/api/test",
    data: data,
    success: (data, status, xhr) => {alert("SUCCESS!")},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType:'json'
  });
```

I know the url and body are correct, I can see the API reacting by initializing the corresponding controller and I think I get a ACK response for the connection:

[image: firefox network]

But before even entering the Method with the Attribute [HttpGet] Firefox throws the error.

When I do the same request in Postman, everything works just fine, though I could imagine, that postman routes every request through their servers, with would eliminate any CORS problems.

Interestingly I get two errors: (sorry, they are German)

[image: CORS errors]

Comment: have you try `builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44314").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it sadly didn't change anything

Comment: have you the same problem with chrome...?

Comment: Using Chrome does not work either:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44314/api/test' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: at least you are sure the problem is coming from your program settings

Comment: Do I? I'm not sure, what causes the problem

Comment: you are using https so, make sure the servers have valid and trusted SSL certificates. Even if CORS is enabled correctly on the server, some browsers (such as Firefox) do not complete cross-origin requests if the SSL certificate itself is invalid.

Comment: Ah yes, I already checked that. I made an exception inside of firefox. But I got it working now and posted an answer. Thank you all für your suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so changing the code from

```
app.UseCors(options =>
   options.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44314").AllowAnyMethod());
```

to

```
app.UseCors(
   options => options
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
  );
```

did the trick. Apparently the url I had provided as an exception was not correct (?). I still don't know, **WHY** my code didn't work, but this is the solution for me. If someone can explain, what I did wrong, please leave a comment, I would like to know!